# meta-analysis using metafor pre-post difference without control comparison group

Tags: meta-analysis

I am conducting a meta-analysis using metafor looking at within subject differences (no control comparison group). My outcome is continuous.

This is the syntax I am using:
data <- escalc(measure="SMCR", m1i=m_post, m2i=m_pre, sd1i=sd_pre, ni=N, ri=ri, data=data) 
and the following for the actual meta-analysis:
ma_model<-rma(yi, vi, data=data, method="FE", digits=2) 
I wasn't sure if this is correct as this syntax calculates the logodds[image]. This is the output I get:

Any help would be much appreciated!! thank you.

Comment: What makes you think a log odds was calculated?

Comment: thanks for your message. from the readings, I thought it is a log odds...I am used to cohen d effect sizes and this is my first time using metafor. Do you think the syntax I used is correct for pre-post differences without a control? Also please let me know if you have any relevant examples/readings you could post? thank you so much!!

Comment: You are not putting log odds ratios in, so you are not getting a log odds out. You are analyzing standardized mean changes (using raw score standardization), so this is what the estimate also stands for.

Comment: great, thank you. Does this analysis sound correct to you? I was confused because the studies included in this meta-analysis did not include control comparison groups. thanks again for your help! much appreciated!

Comment: I am sorry, but I cannot tell you whether your analysis is correct or not and it would not be ethical for me to make such a statement. I know nothing about the goals of your analysis, the studies you have collected, the data that have been extracted, and so on. The code you posted computes standardized mean differences and then pools these values using a fixed-effects model. If this is what you wanted to do, then this is what you have done.

Comment: Totally understood. thanks again!